# Eigen library, multiply columns of matrix by square matrix

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication, eigen

I want to transform each column of a matrix M by an operator N. Eigen allows to express this in terms of pre-multiplication:

```
M.colwise() *= N;
```

But the multiplication `M_j * N` is mathematically undefined.

Is there some way to avoid writing a loop?

Comment: @DumbCoder I'd need to define a typedef to map the columns onto `std::array` or the like. Eigen doesn't provide column iterators.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to multiply each column of `M` by `N` from the left, just perform a normal matrix-matrix-multiplication:

```
M = N * M;
```

This will evaluate `N*M` into a temporary which is then moved to `M`. 
If you do this a lot and want to re-use the allocated memory for that, declare a temporary matrix `M_temp` somewhere before and write

```
M_temp.noalias() = N * M;
M.swap(M_temp);  // M_temp has the old memory of M; Swapping is O(1)
```

If you are afraid of too much memory consumption, you can write something like

```
for(long i=0; i<M.cols()-3; i+=4)
    M.middleCols<4>(i) = N * M.middleCols<4>(i);
M.rightCols(M.cols()%4) = N * M.rightCols(M.cols()%4);
```